# Hash opencv frames to memoize function (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, hash

I'm replacing portions of a video with frames from a different video. I want the chosen replacement frames to be as similar as possible to the original.

I'm using this function to find the closest frame to the portion:

```
import functools
import cv2

@functools.cache
def closest_frame(frame, frames):
    return min(
        frames, key=lambda x: cv2.norm(frame, x, cv2.NORM_L2)
    )
```

This is an expensive computation because frames is really long. So I added functools cache. However, OpenCV frames can't be cached like that: `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer the question of "how to make ndarray hashable": convert each of the arrays in the ndarray, including the outermost, into tuples. Since these are immutable, the result will be hashable. You can simply use the following:
`hash_frame = tuple(tuple(sub) for sub in frame)` for the resultant minimum frame you find, and then return this one in your function.

However, this will only solve your problem if the query frames you are using are repetitive in the first video, since these are the ones getting hashed.

The way hashing in this case should work is: have a hash function which can generate keys for all the images in the dataset which is being accessed,based on some function using which you will objectively determine how "similar" two images are. Do the same for the query image which is being used. Then , these hash values can be compared, so as to give the "nearest" image/images.

The problem of quickly finding the "most similar" image out of a collection of images, given a query image, can be tackled in two ways:

1. Using an appropriate **hash function** to generate useful keys given a particular data point (image). There can be two varieties here: **first**, when each image can be used to create a unique key. In this case, when we query, we will first use the same function with our query, get a key value, and then use an efficient method to find the same/closest key in the cache (eg: if the keys can be arranged in descending order, then we use binary search). The **other case** could be when different images in the dataset produce the same  key on using the hash function. In this case, when we query, we will be able to find the "batch" of most similar images in `O(1)` time, and can then further query this small batch to find the most appropriate image in amortized constant time. This second query could involve, as you are using, euclidean distance.
2. Using something like a **KD-Tree** to first create a hierarchical configuration of all the frames in the second video (takes `O(nlog(n))` time) and then querying the tree each time with each of your query frames. Query will take `O(log(n))` in the worst case per frame.

In both these approaches, you will have to decide what method to use to quantify the images, on some basis, so that the hash-map, or the tree, can be created.

Some popular functions, based on algorithms, for creating a useful and hashable representation for each image can be: LBP, HOG, Color Histogram, SIFT etc. You may even use a pre-trained CNN to get a feature representation from each image.

You can look up KD-Tree implementation libraries for python, like scikit-learn.

Cheers.